# Selenium IDE sendkeys() without target

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-ide

i'm using selenium IDE for automation testing, i tried to use keypress on selenium, but because my site blocking any click and can only use keyboard for operating, i cant use sendkeys()  to run it with selenium IDE because the empty target, is that possible to use sendkey without target? or is that another way to press key without target?

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

In regular Selenium you can sendKeys without a target web element with [Actions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html).
As I see [here](https://www.qafox.com/new-selenium-ide-using-send-keys-command/) this can also be done with Selenium IDE.
There are more additional documentations and tutorials about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use ActionChains in regular Selenium, as mentioned in the previous answer. This definitely will work. But I am needed to use Selenium IDE.

A work around might be executing some JavaScript with the `execute script` command in Selenium IDE to trigger the key press that you need. That might work. I have found some code snippets online for that, but haven't yet worked it out. Actually I'm surprised that there's not a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

command : send keys | ${KEY_CTRL+KEY_ALT+KEY_SHIFT+KEY_F1}

INF : https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/xtype#vs_type

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).